# 入力の先頭を表示するPythonらしいプログラムの書き方

Tags: python

自然数Nをコマンドライン引数などの手段で受け取り，入力のうち先頭のN行だけを表示せよ.というものをPythonで書いたのですが、とりあえず書けただけ感が否めないコードになってしまいました。もう少しPythonらしい書き方ができないでしょうか。

```
import sys

i = 0
with open("hightemp.txt", "r") as f:
    whole_str = f.readlines()

while(i != int(sys.argv[1])): 
    print(whole_str[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

可読性などに問題がなければあまり細かいこと気にしなくてもいいと思いますが、以下のようにも書けます:

```
import sys

with open("hightemp.txt") as f:
    for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])):
        print(f.readline())
```

Comment: `f.readline()` だけですと改行コード(`\r` や `\n`)が残ってしまうので、Hironsan の回答にある様に `rstrip()` で除去するか、`print(f.readline(), end='')` とする方が良いかと(Python3の場合)。また、`hightemp.txt` の行数以上の値を引数(`sys.argv[1]`)に指定した場合に余分な空白行が出力されてしまいます(`print(..., end='')`とすれば問題なし)。

Comment: 「f.readline() だけですと改行コード(\r や \n)が残ってしまうので」それは質問の内容から逸脱していると判断してオリジナルを尊重しています。

Answer (score 2):

```py
import sys
from itertools import islice

n = int(sys.argv[1])
with open("hightemp.txt") as f:
    for line in islice(f, n):
        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```